# Rename specific a component of file names using a list

Tags: matlab, rename

I have a number of files that look like this:

```
imgDATA_subj001_log000_sess001_at.img
imgDATA_subj001_log000_sess001_cn.img
imgDATA_subj001_log000_sess001_cx.img
imgDATA_subj001_log000_sess002_at.img
imgDATA_subj001_log000_sess002_cn.img
imgDATA_subj001_log000_sess002_cx.img
imgDATA_subj002_log000_sess001_at.img
```

...

I want to rename a specific numeric part of the file name after **subj** . For instance, subj001, subj002, subj003, etc. would be renamed to subj014, subj027,subj65, etc. but preserve the rest of the file name. I have the list of new names but not sure how to look for old names and match with the new names then do the renaming. I tried using loops and `fileparts` but I don't know how to isolate the subj*** component. I could do `move` but that would be very inefficient. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think the function `strrep` could be useful for you. You do the following inorder to avoid renaming wrong files: `subj002` -> `MODsubj014` .... And in the End delete the `MOD` part

Comment: Thank you! strrep was indeed the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the portions of the filename that you want to replace specifically, ie you know that subj001 = subj014 then what you should do is use a dir command to get the list of files in the existing directory. 
This will give you a list of the files,

```
f=dir(imgData*.img)
for somecounter=1:length(f)

    filename=f(somecounter).name

    newname=strrep(filename,'subj001','subj014')
    movefile(filename,newname)

end
```

Obviously you'll want to setup an array of each of the individual names to match up and iterate through that.

Comment: Thank you. I almost got there when you posted the answer. The movefile finished that up for me!